# find regex for validating terms (keyword) input

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

unfortunately i'm poor in regex! can you guide me to write a regex in javascript which can determine my terms input box. a user should input terms with this format:

```
#(all alphanumeric chars + blank + dash + quotation )
```

for example:

```
#keyword1#key word2#keyword3#key-word4#key'word5
```

and these inputs should be illegal:

```
#####
##keyword1#key2#
# #keyword
#!%^&
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/#[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9 '-]+/
```

When you said "# #keyword" should be invalid, I've assumed you mean "# " should be invalid and "#keyword" should be extracted from that string. The first 'box' means a keyword will always begin with a lowercase letter, uppercase letter, or number. If thats too restrictive and you want to allow for example "#-keyword", just add dash in before the first close-square-bracket, like so:

```
/#[a-zA-Z0-9-][a-zA-Z0-9 '-]+/
```

And to return an array of results in javascript, apply it to the string using the "global" modifier ('g' after the second slash):

```
arrayOfKeywords = keywordString.match(/#[a-zA-Z0-9-][a-zA-Z0-9 '-]+/g);
```

You may wish to see this code at [my test page](http://burfdl.com/stackoverflow/4987453/). Regular-expressions.info is a useful site to learn more about regular expressions. They also have an [interactive page to test regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) on, which can be useful when playing around.

Comment: thanks burfdl..  i'll test it; but i don't want dash at the end and my another problem is that i wanna to use arabic chars! what i should write? is this okay: /#[a-zA-Z{Arabic}0-9-][a-zA-Z{Arabic}0-9 ']+/      i use this ref: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html

Comment: Unfortunately javascript [isn't very well internationalised](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint) so does not support `\p{Arabic}`. It does support unicode escaping, so you could use `\u0600-\u06FF` to approximate it. However, the full range will probably include characters you don't want. See the unicode listing for arabic [here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) and chop them into groups (eg: `/#[\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]/` should match arabic numbers in the form "#123#456"). Sorry I don't speak arabic better! :)

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote a term is specified by:

```
/#[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]+/
```

Repeat that pattern, and force it to contain the start and end of the string with `^` and `$`.

```
/^(#[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]+)+$/
```